# Magento2 : Add Password strength meter in login form

Tags: magento2, login, form-validation, password

How to add Password strength meter in customer login form?

```
<item name="authentication" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/authentication</item>
    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">authentication</item>
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <!--Additional authentication fields-->
        <item name="errors" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/authentication-messages</item>
            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">messages</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
...
...
<div class="field field-password required">
  <label for="login-password" class="label"><span data-bind="i18n: 'Password'"></span></label>
  <div class="control">
      <input type="password"
             class="input-text"
             id="login-password"
             name="password"
             data-bind="attr: {autocomplete: autocomplete}"
             data-validate="{required:true}"
             autocomplete="off"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: find below answer that will solved your concern https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/223624/magento2-add-password-strength-meter-in-login-form/223642#223642

Comment: Did you got this solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override login file into your theme if not override yet.

> app\design\frontend[VENDOR][THEME]\Magento_Customer\templates\form\login.phtml

In above override phtml file, after password input field or next to password input field add below code

```
<div id="password-strength-meter-container" data-role="password-strength-meter" aria-live="polite">
    <div id="password-strength-meter" class="password-strength-meter">
        <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Password Strength')) ?>:
        <span id="password-strength-meter-label" data-role="password-strength-meter-label">
            <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('No Password')) ?>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        ".field.password": {
            "passwordStrengthIndicator": {
                "formSelector": "form.form-login"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Note:**  in **formSelector** enter form element class or id, In my case I have form class "**form-login**" so I added "form.form-login" in formSelector.

After adding these line **flush cache** and see store front you will get password meter in login page.

Comment: that's working in login page,but how to do it in my case after overriding on checkout page?  `module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\form\element\email.html`

Comment: @KetanKpBorada, if this answer working for you in login page please mark this as acceptable answer and rise a new question for checkout related. sure i will help you for above mention comment as well.

Comment: thanks,but i dont want it in login form,even not anybody want to use it in login form

Comment: @KetanKpBorada, Agree with your concern but you asked a question and you got your answer which suite to your question. I feel that is a valid solution. it's not matter you use or not but future if some one want same then they get this as a valid solution. hope you got my point. else your choice.

Answer (score 1):

html

```html
<div class="field password required col-12 col-sm-6">
   <div class="control">
      <label for="password" class="label">
      <span class="customrequire" data-bind="i18n: 'Password'"></span>
      </label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password"
         class="input-text"
         data-validate-customer-password="true"
         data-password-min-length="8"
         data-password-min-character-sets="3"
         data-bind="attr: {placeholder: $t('********')}, afterRender: afterRenderCustomPassword"
         data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-customer-password':true}"
         autocomplete="off">
      <div id="password-strength-meter-container" data-role="password-strength-meter" aria-live="polite">
         <div id="password-strength-meter" class="password-strength-meter">
            <span id="password-strength-meter-label" data-role="password-strength-meter-label" data-bind="i18n: 'Password Strength'">
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

js

```js
define(['uiComponent', 'ko','jquery','mage/url','mage/mage','Magento_Customer/js/password-strength-indicator', 'mage/translate'],
    function(Component, ko, $, url, passwordForce,$t){
    return Component.extend({
        initialize: function(){
            this._super();
        },
        afterRenderCustomPassword: function (){
            passwordForce.passwordStrengthIndicator({
                "formSelector": "form.form-create-account"
            }, $('.field.password.required.col-12.col-sm-6'));
        }
  })
});
```

Comment: With some adjustments, this works for me! +1.